# Difference between a choice and a sequence when creating an eclipse extetension point

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Could anyone please explain the difference between a choice and a sequence when creating an eclipse extension point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [schema definition help page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/schema_editor/page_schema_definition.htm):

> Example:
>
> The extension element specifies that a sequence of one or more shortcut elements are allowed as its legal children.
> An element reference is used to represent the shortcut element.
> A **Sequence compositor is used to represent a sequence of elements**.

[image: sequence]

Extension Point Elements Section 2

> The shortcut element specifies that either a description or category element is allowed as its legal child.
> Element references are used to represent the description and category elements.
> A **Choice compositor is used to represent a choice of elements**.

[image: choice]

As this [thread mentions](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/103301/), this is [standard XML Schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp), which includes:

- [XML Schema choice Element](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp)
- [XML Schema sequence Element](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp)